# how to print russian symbols(text) in j2me code using netbeans tool

Tags: java

can anyone tell me how to print russian symbols in j2me using netbeans...

[1]to do so i used custom text method....in this method we add a font strip having russian symbols and put in resource folder.
[2]in the source code we take array of same symbole and also their width and use this array to print the russian text...
[3] but while doing so the netbean fails to read the array and put the question mark for the symbols which it dont recognise....

thanks and please tell me the valid reason and solution to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your source files have UTF-8 encoding set. I use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) for this purpose. There is menu "encoding". And it shows the current encoding and allows to change encoding of the file.

If you want to change encoding cut the whole text (CTRL+X), change encoding, and paste text again. After that save the file.

If you just change encoding without cut/paste, then some non-ansi strings in your code will become non-readable.

Comment: I see two reasons. The first: your font does not support russian unicode symbols. The second, there is a problem with encoding of source files, one or more of them are not in UTF-8. To overcome that use unicode character codes, instead of characters itself to get a russian letter and print it on the device display.